How to extract SpatialPoints after running a Constrained Latin Hypercube analysis
I performed a constrained Latin Hypercube analysis where I get important locations from a raster stack, however I want to convert the results obtained from the clhs to spatial points.
I do the following:

sample1=clhs(SI_T, size = 50)
sample1
[1]  2243  9990   687  7635  8553 11018  8634 10379  2967  5349  6651  8807  1197  8024  4559  5297  1352  4598  8018  6725
[21]    22  5133 10878  7688  3937   857 10442   998 10414  3120  9452  9397  1924  1029  6109  4133 10460  4985  1138  4075
[41]  8422  6701  1259  5399  6276  3066  3299  6555  5606 10176
x1=as(sample1,'SpatialPoints')
Error in as(sample1, "SpatialPoints") :
no method or default for coercing “numeric” to “SpatialPoints”

SI_T is the raster stack where I ran the clhs analysis, and then I want to located the spatial points estimated for sample1... I tried to convert them into SpatialPoints but the pop out results is:
Error in as(sample1, "SpatialPoints") :
no method or default for coercing “numeric” to “SpatialPoints”
The Raster info is:
class      : RasterStack
dimensions : 129, 178, 22962, 1382  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.0002709715, 0.0002709715  (x, y)
extent     : -105.0429, -104.9947, 23.87611, 23.91106  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
Any help would be really appreciate it.
Samu
I don´t what to try.
